# Linking thumbnails to video files, and adding a title

Tags: image-processing, linked-list, html5-video

Long shot here but...

I have 200 thumbnails, and 50 videos. That's 4 thumbnails per video that I can choose from, but I only need to link 1 thumbnail to the appropriate video.

So I have
video1thumb1, video1thumb2.jpg, video1thumb3.jpg, video1thumb4.jpg  ---- video1.avi
video2thumb1, video2thumb2.jpg, video2thumb3.jpg, video2thumb4.jpg  ---- video2.avi
video3thumb1, video3thumb2.jpg, video3thumb3.jpg, video3thumb4.jpg  ---- video3.avi
... and so on... Images are in the /Image folder, and videos are in the /videos folder.

Now... Is there a script/program/code out there that will allow me to choose the best image or each video AND add a title to each video?

Comment: This is an interesting question but at the moment it is a little too vague.  What environment are you working in (e.g. Linux)?  Which language are you most comfortable using for this task -- Python, bash, MS-DOS batch (yikes!).  I've seen that you use ffmpeg from your other posts -- please be more specific.  Also, what do you mean by "add a title to each video"?  Does this mean a title frame (or frames), overlaying the same text over every frame, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You can break down your problem into separate parts:

1. Pick the best thumbnail out of 3.
2. Add title to each video.

For the first part, you can easily get this done using bash (if you're on Linux) and imagemagick (cross-platform imaging library).

For each video, you would want to do something like this (I sense a `for` loop):

```
filename=videoX.avi

#
# Strip the file extension.
#
vname="${filename%.*}"
#
# Show the three thumbnails side by side.
#
montage $vname-thumb1.jpg $vname-thumb2.jpg $vname-thumb3.jpg -adjoin - | display
#
# Get the user to select the best thumbnail.
#
echo "Which thumbnail do you prefer: 1, 2 or 3?"
read -n 1 -s reply
if [ "$reply" = "1" ] || [ "$reply" = "2" ] || [ "$reply" = "3" ]
then
    cp $vname-thumb$reply.jpg $vname-selected.jpg
else        
    echo "Invalid response: $reply"
fi
```